# Access items from a nested has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models: User, School, and Applicant.

A user `has_many :schools`, a school `has_many :applicants` and `belongs_to :user`, and an applicant `belongs_to :school`.

I'd like to be able to list applicants that belong to any school that belongs to a particular user. I thought I should be able to do it with

```
current_user.schools.applicants.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

That is not working as it is giving this error:

```
undefined method `applicants' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fb9da274110>
```

How can I access these applicants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot chain `has_many` associations like that. Create a `has_many :through` association on the user model:

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_many :applicants, :through => :schools
```

Then you can call

```
current_user.applicants.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

From the [guide on ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association):

> The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up “shortcuts” through nested has_many associations. [...]

Comment: It would make more sense for a user to `have_many :applications, class_name: "Applicant", through: :schools`, giving you a `current_user.applications` association. Users don't have applicants. Otherwise, I agree, this is the best solution.

Comment: Sure, but for the purpose of this question, I'd like to keep it simple.

Comment: Great, that works too.. I think this solution is a little more elegant than using a select statement in the controller.

Comment: Both approaches work. You could simply wrap @meagar's solution into an instance method of your user model.

Comment: In this case, users kind of do have applicants. In the beginning, users belonged to a school, but I have had to modify to allow a user to manage multiple schools. So the user now needs to review applications submitted by applicants from multiple schools. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Associations can be chained only so long as the previous association resolves to a single record (ie, you can chain `belongs_to.belongs_to.has_many`, but never `has_many.has_many` - that's what `has_many :through` is for).

If you want applicants, you need to actually select applicants:

```
Applicant.where(school_id: current_user.schools.pluck(:id)).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... that makes sense and fixed the issue.

Comment: You might consider adding a `has_many :through` if what you're looking for are all applications *by* a user. But, it sounds like you're looking for all applicants for all schools a user is currently attending, *not* all of a user's current applications, which means it really shouldn't be a `has_many :through` for the User model.